# Erro ao passar props com objetos literais via v-bind="object"

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

No Vue é descrito na documentação que se deseja passar todas as propriedades de um objeto via `props` é possível passar o mesmo da seguinte forma

```
# data do componente
post: {
  title: 'Título da post',
  content: '...'
}

# template

<blog-post v-bind="post"></blog-post>
```

Testei essa abordagem mas recebo um erro. Eis meu código:

```js
const blogPost = {
    props: ['post'],
    template: '\
    <div>\
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>\
      <p>{{ content }}</p>\
    </div>'
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    post: {
      title: 'Minha jornada com Vue',
      content: '...'
    }
  },
  components: {
    'blog-post': blogPost
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <blog-post v-bind="post"></blog-post>
</div>
```

```
# Erro

title is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao dar o `v-bind` você deve apontar a `prop` que deseja atribuir, e na interpolação usar a `prop` como objeto...

```js
const blogPost = {
    props: ['post'],
    template: '\
    <div>\
      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>\
      <p>{{ post.content }}</p>\
    </div>'
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    post: {
      title: 'Minha jornada com Vue',
      content: '...'
    }
  },
  components: {
    'blog-post': blogPost
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <blog-post v-bind:post="post"></blog-post>
</div>
```